# OneSignal send js variable on web notifications

Tags: javascript, php, push-notification, notifications, onesignal

Does anyone know how to send js variable on web notifications contents?

I'm trying the below code but s not working and I get empty content for it.

I added my PHP variable to JS variable noticeText and the content is there but in notification content shows nothing.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
                                var noticeText = "<?php echo $noticeTitle; ?>";
    var settings = {
      "async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications",
      "method": "POST",
      "headers": {
        "cookie": "__cfduid=d7e029aceb39ed3bc3b64849b5358bf3a1544538404",
        "authorization": "Basic MzVmZGQ5ZWQtNGI5OC00YTU5LWFhOGUtMTZhZWVmMzg3MGIx",
        "content-type": "application/json"
      },
      "processData": false,
      "data": 
'{"app_id": "dc44e367-f59b-41fd-a7c9-1b25cfd8cb66","included_segments": ["All"],"headings": {"en": "Hey {{ first_name }} {{ last_name }}", "tr": "Turkish {{ first_name }} {{ last_name }}"},"contents": {"en": "{{ noticeText }}", "tr": "Turkish Content"}}'
    }
    
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      console.log(response); 
    });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Direct php echo worked eventualy the trick was to have it in "" an vola works like a charm